# Difference between profile and email scope in Google OAuth 2 flow

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I'm configuring the scopes that my application requires for accessing Google and I can't find the difference between those two:

1. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

In the documentation we can see the following:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email    View your email address
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile    View your basic profile info

However, when I access userinfo via [api-client-library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) I get all the info even in case I don't request one of the scopes.

```
com.google.api.services.oauth2.Oauth2#userinfo
```

Returns complete object. Event if I don't use email scope, email is still returned. But, if I don't use both of the scopes - access is restricted and call fails. The question is what's the difference between these two scopes and which one is preferable?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#google-sign-in

Google Sign-In Scopes

profile: View your basic profile info.

email:   View your email address.

openid:  Authenticate using OpenID Connect.

Basic Profile: ID, Full name, Given Name, Family Name, Image URL.